# Getting "illegal cyclic reference involving object FieldSerializer" when working with annotations

Tags: scala, annotations

I am extracting all annotations of case class properties using this code:

```
val allAnnotations = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass.primaryConstructor
   .typeSignature.paramLists.head.map(_.annotations)
```

Everything is working OK until I add this annotation to one of the case class properties:

```
@(Tag@field)
```

For example:

```
case class Test(@(Tag@field)(10) id1: Int,
                @MyAnnotation(128) id2: String,
                ...)
```

I get this exception:

```
scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$CyclicReference: illegal cyclic reference involving object FieldSerializer
```

Any way of working around it?

Comment: Can you please provide definitions of `MyAnnotation`, `Tag` and `field`?